# ZoomingPDFViewer is not zooming inside a paging enabled UIScrollViewer

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to show single page PDFs horizontally placed so that one can go through pages by swiping left or right. And of course I need to zoom pages.

I implemented it using `UIWebView`s inside a container `UIScrollViewer` with paging enabled. `UIWebView` works as PDF viewer and `UIScrollView` handles page changes. But this implementation is not a good one, it uses too much memory so I decided to use Apple's `ZoomingPDFViewer` instead of `UIWebView`.

My originial code with `UIWebView`s look likes this:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollviewer.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.size = self.scrollviewer.frame.size;

    UIWebView *pageViewer = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    pageViewer.scalesPageToFit = TRUE;
    pageViewer.multipleTouchEnabled = TRUE;

    [self.scrollviewer addSubview:pageViewer];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:address];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [pageViewer loadRequest:req];
}

self.scrollviewer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(nPages * self.scrollviewer.frame.size.width, self.scrollviewer.frame.size.height);
```

This works perfect except it is slow when I have more than 25 pages and Apple doesn't recommend usage of `UIWebView` inside a `UIScrollView` or `UITableView` because touch events can have unexpected results.

So I wanted to change `UIWebView` to `ZoomingPDFViewer` given in the examples by Apple. My new code with `ZoomingPDFViewer` looks like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollviewer.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.size = self.scrollviewer.frame.size;

    PDFScrollView *pageViewer = [[PDFScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [self.scrollviewer addSubview:pageViewer];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:address];
    CGPDFDocumentRef PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url);

    CGPDFPageRef PDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFDocument, 1);
    [(PDFScrollView *)pageViewer setPDFPage:PDFPage];

    CGPDFDocumentRelease(PDFDocument);
}

self.scrollviewer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(nPages * self.scrollviewer.frame.size.width, self.scrollviewer.frame.size.height);
```

This code shows me my PDF pages, I can swipe between pages but I cannot zoom into a page.

I don't know what to do. Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, do you know how to go from one page to another?

Comment: You can get a specific page by changing the second argument of `CGPDFDocumentGetPage` function. But if you want to show all pages than you should create an `ZoomingPDFViewer` object for all pages. The way I did was a horizontal slider filled with `ZoomingPDFViewer`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was when you create a `UIScrollView` programmatically it sets `minimumZoomScale` and `maximumZoomScale` 1.0 by default. So actually my code was working but I didn't know that it was working because it wasn't zooming in or zooming out.

So I added two lines to my code and it worked !!! Here is the changes in my code

```
PDFScrollView *pageViewer = [[PDFScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
pageViewer.minimumZoomScale = 0.2;
pageViewer.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;

[self.scrollviewer addSubview:pageViewer];
```

When I inserted two lines it worked but I was able to zoom in or zoom out infinitely. I wanted to zoom at max scale of 5. So I changed `scrollViewDidEndZooming` method given in the file `PDFScrollView.m`

Default code shipped with Apple's `ZoomingPDFViewer` looks like this:

```
// Set the new scale factor for the TiledPDFView.
_PDFScale *= scale;

// Calculate the new frame for the new TiledPDFView.
CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(_PDFPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);
pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width*_PDFScale, pageRect.size.height*_PDFScale);
```

After changes it looks like:

```
// Set the new scale factor for the TiledPDFView.
_PDFScale *= scale;

self.minimumZoomScale *= 1 / scale;
self.maximumZoomScale *= 1 / scale;

// Calculate the new frame for the new TiledPDFView.
CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(_PDFPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);
pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width*_PDFScale, pageRect.size.height*_PDFScale);
```

Now it works.

Comment: I tried this patch but it's showing weird behavior while zooming. Glitches, jumps, sometimes it zooms out instead of in. Are you sure that setting self.minimumZoomScale *= 1 / scale; works for you?

Comment: i tried it for ios6 and it works but i didn't try it for ios7.